# NodeJS, MongoDB, Aggregation function with $lookup result is empty array []

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

**my grades model is:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var GradeSchema = new Schema({
gID: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'People'},
    grade: Number,
    type: Number
}, {timestamps: true});

var Grade = mongoose.model('Grade', GradeSchema);
module.exports=Grade;
```

**people model is:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PeopleSchema = new Schema({
_id: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Grade' },
    name: String,
    lastName:String,
    phone: String
},{timestamps: true});

var People = mongoose.model('People', PeopleSchema);

module.exports=People;
```

**my aggregate query is:**

```
Grade.aggregate([

      {$lookup:{ from: 'People', localField:'glD', 
        foreignField:'_id',as:'myCustomResut'}},
]).exec((err, result)=>{
      if (err) {
          console.log("error" ,err)
      }
      if (result) {
          console.log(result);
      }
});
```

** but myCustomResut is empty result like myCustomResut []: **
what is wrong with this code?

> [ { _id: 5a13e33e931f7561b85d0840,
>               updatedAt: 2017-11-21T08:26:38.413Z,
>               createdAt: 2017-11-21T08:26:38.413Z,
>               gID: 5a13e33e931f7561b85d083f,
>               grade: 20,
>               type: 2,
>               __v: 0,
>               myCustomResut:: [] },
>             { _id: 5a13e78e4fac5b61ecdbd9ab,
>               updatedAt: 2017-11-21T08:45:02.517Z,
>               createdAt: 2017-11-21T08:45:02.517Z,
>               gID: 5a13e78e4fac5b61ecdbd9aa,
>               grade: 20,
>               type: 2,
>               __v: 0,
>               myCustomResut:: [] } ]

Comment: did u find answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if your collection is really `People`. From experience I know that people created a collection with capital letter but in their database it was with small. So check if it is not `people` instead. It has to do with Mongoose.
So try your aggregation again like that:

```
Grade.aggregate([

      {$lookup:{ from: 'people', localField:'gID', 
        foreignField:'_id',as:'myCustomResut'}},
]).exec((err, result)=>{
      if (err) {
          console.log("error" ,err)
      }
      if (result) {
          console.log(result);
      }
});
```

Here you defined your field `gID` (upper case i):

> var GradeSchema = new Schema({ **gID**: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:
>   'People'}

And here you wrote `glD` (lower case L):

> {$lookup:{ from: 'People', localField:'**glD**'

I updated the code snippet above, so try again, with the collection as `People` or `people`.  But the mistake is definitely the glD. It was also tricky for me to see, because if you read the code like that, it doesn't look like there is a problem. I only realized it's wrong when I went to edit my answer.

Comment: test it by other names but result is myCustomResut[]

Comment: thank you my problem solve whene use {$lookup:{ from: 'people', localField:'glD'

Comment: @FazelNajariyan if your question was answered. Could you please also mark it as answered?

Comment: I have the same issue but I'm not using Mongoose. If I run a query in the Mongodb console it works fine but the same query in NodeJS using the latest version of the 'mongodb' package produces an empty result.  Any ideas?

Comment: @CleytonT. I'm also having the same issue you had.

Answer (score 0):

try to write collection name **peoples** instead of **people**

```
 Grade.aggregate([

      {$lookup:{ from: 'peoples', localField:'gID', 
        foreignField:'_id',as:'myCustomResut'}},
]).exec((err, result)=>{
      if (err) {
          console.log("error" ,err)
      }
      if (result) {
          console.log(result);
      }
});
```